# Instruction not recognized in MarieJS code

Tags: assembly, marie

I have been doing this Marie code and it says it has three errors every time I try to assemble it. I'm unsure on how to go about fixing it. I have tried changing a bunch of things but I still end up with 3 or more errors.
It is telling me instructions are not recognized, Here is where the errors appear, I am very very new to all of this so I am still trying to figure out how it all works, apologies if it is something super simple!
Here is the code and below that will be the image of the errors

```
    org         100
    input
    store       N       
    input
    store       D       
    load        N       
    store       K
    
Outer,  load        K      
    skipcond    800
    jump        Done   
    load        Incr   
    store       Pow
    load        D      
    store       J

Inner,  load        J       
    add         J
    subt        K
    skipcond    000
    jump        AftIn   
    load        J       
    add         J
    store       J
    load        Pow     
    add         Pow
    store       Pow
    
    jump        Inner   
    
AftIn,  load        K       
    subt        J
    store       K
    load        Answer  
    add         Pow
    store       Answer
            
    jump        Outer   

 Done,   load        K       
    skipcond    000
    jump        Disp
    load        Answer
    subt        Incr
Disp,   load        Answer  
    output
    halt
    
N,      dec         0      
D,      dec         0       
K,      dec         0       
J,      dec         0       
Pow,    dec         0       
Answer, dec         0       
Incr,   dec         1
```

[image]

I am using a MarieSim JAR application from 2009 to run the code.

Comment: It assembles ok on https://marie.js.org/.  What tooling are you using?  In any case, looks like it doesn't recognize `SUBT`, maybe try `SUB` instead, or try lower or mixed case (`subt` or `Subt`)??  (Note, marie.js.org doesn't like the space in the 1st column of the `Done,` line.)

Comment: Thank you very much! the "subt" change to "sub" worked perfectly!

Comment: Please let us know what tooling you're using, for future readers having the same/similar problem.

Comment: the program I am using for it just says it is MarieSim, it is a jar file if that helps any, it is also from 2009 if that helps at all to get a scope of what it is exactly

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the assembler you're using doesn't like `SUBT` but that the assembly code is otherwise in good shape.  Maybe try `SUB` instead of `SUBT`.